# PHP Dependent Drop Down Lists

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I know several similar questions have been posted related to dependent drop down lists, but I can't quite find the answer I'm looking for - apologies if it's already been covered!

What I'm trying to do is this: I'm building a webpage which will have two related drop down lists; the second's values being dependent on the first's selection. The first is a "Product", the second is a "Size"... so far, so good. The options included in each list ultimately come from a database - Products list is as follows:

```
<select id="product-list">
    <option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
    <?php
        if ($res2 = mysqli_query($con,$getproducts)) {
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($res2)){
                $pid= $row2[0];
                $pname= $row2[1];
                echo "<option value='" . $pid . "'>" . $pname . "</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

This one works just fine so no problems there. However, I'm struggling to get my head around the second list...

The query which retrieves the Sizes is this:

```
$getsizes = "SELECT productid,displayname,price from productsizelookup where formatid = $formatid";
```

I only have two products (for now), so this query will retrieve all possible sizes, so what I now need is a subset of records from this query based on the product id being supplied by the value of the option in the first select list.

I don't know if this will require another query to the database, and I've read somewhere that I might need AJAX. Is anyone able to assist, or perhaps provide a gentle nudge in the right direction?

### EDIT

I tried adding a div block as follows where I wanted the drop down to appear:

```
<div id="wrap_size"></div>
```

Then at the bottom of the page added the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change', '#product-list', function(e) {
        var pid = $(this).val();
        var data = {'pid':pid};
        var url = 'size.php';
        $.post(url, data, function(res) {
            $('#wrap_size').html(res);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally, my size.php file:

```
<?php

include("include/dbvariables.php");

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$pid = !empty($_POST["pid"]) ? $_POST["pid"] : 0;

$getsizes = "SELECT productid,displayname,price from productsizelookup where formatid = $formatid and productid = $pid";

echo '<select id="size-list">';
echo '<option>-- Please Select --</option>';

if ($res3 = mysqli_query($con,$getsizes)) {
    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_row($res3)){
        $sid= $row3[0];
        $pid= $row3[1];
        $size= $row3[2];
        $price= $row3[3];
        echo '<option value="'.$sid.'">'.$size.'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

The only option I now get in the list is the "-- Please Select --" option... Sorry if I'm way off course with this!!

Many thanks

Comment: Check this http://turson.pl/blog/dynamiczne-zalezne-selecty/ there's a demo also

Comment: Great effort.  At first glance:  You should wrap your jQuery code in `$(document).ready(......);`  Do you also link to the jQuery library?

Comment: `pid` is not being passed through.  In addition to using `document.ready`, something like this should also be on your page: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>`

Comment: Just added `$(document).ready(...)` and already have references to jquery libraries but still same result... drop down appearing but no options shown. Am I using/accessing the `$pid` correctly in size.php?

Comment: If `pid` is an integer your sql query looks ok to me.  Do you get javascript errors?  If you use Chrome, you can see this by pressing `Shift-Ctrl-J` at the same time and looking at `Console`.

Comment: What is `$formatid`?  Is that defined in `dbvariables.php?`

Comment: Sorry, `$formatid` is a variable I collect from another query prior to running the second query - I know that this returns a value of 1 in this case, as I CAN get the "Size" box populated using that query alone. I'm struggling with the `$pid`. I don't have any JS errors in the console

Comment: OK Debug time: To see if `pid` is read by your jQuery code, put `alert(pid);` after the line where you read it's value.  Put `echo "Post: " . print_r($_POST);` at the top of the script `size.php` to see if anything is POSTed.  In your SQL query, replace `$pid` by an actual value of `pid` to see if your query is working.  If `pid` is a string it should be between (single) quotes in your query.

Comment: I think I'm almost there -  it seems you were right about the `$formatid`... it's not getting picked up in the SQL query, perhaps because the query is now in a new page(?). It DOES have a value in the calling page. The `$pid` IS being set correctly and hardcoding the formatid fixes the issue. how can I pass this value across to size.php and use it there?

Comment: Sorry I was held up... Yes if you use `formatid` in the calling page you will have to pass it through. You can put it into the `data` array if you have it available as a php variable.  I will edit my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly, how I would do this:

I check the onChange event of the first select list using jQuery.

```
$(document).on('change', '#product-list', function(e) { ... });
```

I get the selected value and pass this as data via a jquery AJAX call to a server-side script.

```
var pid = $(this).val();
var data = {'pid':pid};
var url = 'select_size.php';
$.post(url, data, function(res) {
    $('#wrap_size').html(res);
});
```

The script uses the selected value to make a SQL call to get the option values for the second select list.

```
$pid = !empty($_POST["pid"]) ? $_POST["pid"] : 0;
```

// SQL QUERY HERE, CONSTRUCT SELECT LIST

The script then constructs and echos the HTML for this second select list.

This result of the AJAX call is then written into a container div '#wrap_size' where the second select list should appear.

**EDIT:**

If `$formatid` is created in the calling page and used in the `size.php` script, it needs to get passed through just like `pid`.

Change your javascript to this:

```
var data = {'pid':pid, 'formatid':<?php $formatid; ?>};
```

Or create a hidden input whose value is `$formatid`, and read that value: `var formatid = $('input:hidden[name=formatid]').val();  var data = {pid:pid, formatid:formatid};`

Of course, you also have to read its value in your script:

```
$formatid = !empty($_POST["formatid"]) ? $_POST["formatid"] : 0;
```

Comment: Really appreciate the reply, I'm new to php/jquery/ajax etc so will do my best to try and implement your suggestions before marking as answered! thanks again.

Comment: I've edited my original question taking into consideration your suggestions - hoping you could take a look at where I messed up! Thanks, Lee

Comment: That's great - I made a comment underneath your post.

Comment: Awesome, just had to tweak it to `<?php echo $formatid; ?>` and works an absolute treat - thanks for all your help, I owe you a beer!

Comment: Glad if I helped! I fixed the bug in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have this piece of html:

```
<select name="first" id="first"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
<select name="second" id="second"><!-- to be updated --></select>
```

I will give a jquery example because is smaller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#first').on('change', function() {
       // ajax request to your page that returns the sizes
       if($(this).val()) {
           $.get('/my/sizes/' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
              $('#second').html(data);
           });
       }
    });
</script>
```

Then '/my/sizes/product_id' page should return the exact  elements based on that product id, similar with how you build the product list.